# I am facing issue while running my coded ui test as part of build. My coded ui test have DDA attached to it as part of CSV files

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am facing issue while running my coded ui test as part of build. My coded ui test have DDA attached to it as part of CSV files. While build succeeded, coded ui test failed with the following error message.

"The unit test adapter failed to connect to the data source or to read the data. For more information on troubleshooting this error, see "Troubleshooting Data-Driven Unit Tests" (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=62412) in the MSDN Library.Error details: The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'DDAAccounts.csv'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly".

Coded UI test are running successfully as part of the build, but the test which are having CSV files attached as part of DDA are only failing.

Can anyone suggest a possible solution.

Comment: What is "DDA"? Do you have CSV data driven tests that do not use DDA and do they work? If I ignore the DDA part then I would suggest that the CSV files are not being deployed to the place where Coded UI expects to find them when it runs the test.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you've found an answer to this already, but be sure to check that your .csv's Build Action is listed as content and the Copy to Output Directory is set to "Copy if Newer".  Per this article=> [Unit Testing Error - The unit test adapter failed to connect to the data source or to read the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783045/unit-testing-error-the-unit-test-adapter-failed-to-connect-to-the-data-source)